# Emscripten OOB Exception within C from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, arrays, pointers, emscripten

I'm trying to pass an array of strings from JS to C using Emscripten. I pass my array to C but when I try to deference, it does not work, it raises "index out of bounds". I've tried many different things so I'll post the minimal amount of code that can reproduce the issue (at least on my machine!). I'm sure I missed something...

Basically trying to put a string into an array (of strings) and give that to C for printing (I'm doing other stuff of course). Feel free to change the "gmp_*" or "mpz_*" to your (that's not the problem).

Javascript:

```
    var nbData = 1;
    var nbColPerData = 1;
    var data = new Uint32Array(nbColPerData);
    data[0] = this.i2wasm(this.mod);

    var nBytes = data.length * data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    var dataPtr = Module._malloc(nBytes);
    var dataHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAP8.buffer,dataPtr,nBytes);
    dataHeap.set(new Uint8Array(data.buffer));

    // create array of pointers
    var pointers = new Uint32Array(nbData);
    for (var i =0; i < pointers.length; i++) {
        pointers[i] = dataPtr + i * data.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
        console.log("pointers["+i+"] = " + pointers[i].toString(16));
    }

    // create pointer array on the heap
    var nPointerBytes= pointers.length * pointers.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
    var pointerPtr = Module._malloc(nPointerBytes);
    var pointerHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAP8.buffer, pointerPtr,nPointerBytes);
    pointerHeap.set( new Uint8Array(pointers.buffer));

    printIntMatrix(pointerHeap,nbData)

    Module._free(pointerHeap.byteOffset);
    Module._free(dataHeap.byteOffset);
```

i2wasm (hexadecimal string to int array for wasm, works properly):

```
    return allocate(intArrayFromString(integer),'i8',ALLOC_NORMAL);
```

C code:

```
void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE printInt(char *hex) {
    mpz_t n;
    mpz_init(n);
    printf("printing INT at %p\n",hex);
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // HERE IT PANICS !
    /////////////////////////////////////
    printf("printing INT value: %c\n",*hex);
    if (mpz_set_str(n,hex,16) != 0) {
        printf("hexadecimal invalid");
        return;
    }

    gmp_printf("printInt: %Zd\n",n);
    mpz_clear(n);
}

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE printIntMatrix(char **mat, int n) {
    printf("printIntMatrix !!\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("matrix[%d] => \n",i);
        printf("matrix[%d] => %p\n",i,mat[i]);
        printInt(mat[i]);
        printf("matrix[%d] => %p DONE\n",i,mat[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i2wasm()` returns `char*`, so `dataPtr` is `char**`.

And `_printIntMatrix(pointerHeap, nbData)` means `_printIntMatrix(pointerHeap | 0, nbData)`, eventually it is `_printIntMatrix(NULL, nbData)`.

So if `printIntMatrix` doesn't need `char ***mat`, `_printIntMatrix(dataPtr, nbData);` would work.